# filter answers by tags when viewing profile

Tags: discussion, support, search

This question is very basic so please bear with me. I cannot figure out how to sort or filter answers by tags when I view my history of posts and replies in my math.se profile. It has got to the point where sometimes it takes me quite some time to locate an answer that I know is there but I don't remember when I posted it. Filtering by tags would really be handy here.

Thanks and happy computing.

Comment: You can either type, for example, `user:44883 [pi]` into a search box. Alternatively you can go to your (or somebody else's, as I just did) profile, and click `Summary`. Look for the heading **Tags**, and click the greyed number next to the tag of interest. By doing that I was taken to [this page](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:44883+[pi]).

Comment: See also: [Sorting my questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28589).

Answer (score 2):

*Sorting* by tags would not be  very practical, because questions usually have multiple tags. If some sort of dictionary order is imposed, then you'd have to know whether the question had other tags than come earlier in the dictionary than the tag you are thinking about.

*Filtering* by tags is already available, via the search box. Type `[tag-name] user:me` to get the list of all your posts in the tag "tag-name". You can also combine two or more tags in the search:

- `[tag1] [tag2] user:me` to find your posts with tag1 **and** tag2.
- `[tag1] or [tag2] user:me` to find your posts with tag1 **or** tag2.

Adding `is:answer` limits the results to only answers.

Comment: Thanks ever so much that was in fact what I was looking for. I forgot the think-before-you-post rule. ;-) Just tried it and it works. Upvoted.

Comment: The tags shown in your profile are also linked to these filtered search results.