# Sorting my questions

Tags: support

Is there a way to sort questions I have asked by categories? For example:

"number theory", "Linear Algebra", "Calculus". And each question will correspond

to its topic.

Comment: See also: [filter answers by tags when viewing profile](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11940).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is essentially possible using "search".

Search for: `user:me is:question [number-theory]`  to get all your questions in tag [number-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory).

Another way is to go to your user-page, activity tab, and to click the tags name in the section "tags". This will give all posts though not just questions. Moreover it ultimately is just a short-cut for search.

Comment: Might get repeat postings, though, if the user asked any questions with two or more tags that they consider significant.  You didn't claim that; @quid, this is more a comment for the OP.